# Нужна ли авторизация для веб-приложения с БД?

Tags: php, база-данных

Работа сводится к тому, чтобы создать базы данных (которая будет пополняться и меняться) сотрудников и отдельно студентов. Чтобы просматривалась информация о них и т д. Для входа в систему делать логин-пароль?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно делать. Иначе кто угодно сможет менять информацию. Можно сделать 2 режима. В одном будет только просмотр информации о сотрудниках и студентах. А во втором режиме, уже помимо просмотра возможно будет изменять информацию о сотрудниках и студентах. Для доступа ко второму режиму нужно будет авторизоваться в системе.